# Ckeditor. The blur events gets called after the click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

Can I some how give preference Ckeditor events. 
The blur events gets called after the click event .

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    alert("btn click");
});

ckeditor.on('blur', function (event, sourceElement) {
    alert("editor blur");
});
```

Comment: This is because the click event calls alert and alert takes away the focus to itself. Can you try a `console.log()` for debugging

Comment: No the issue isnt that. I get btn-click alert first then editor blur alert. 
Console.log also wont work!

Comment: could you replace the alerts with console.log() and at least give a try :)